# difference between Wald and LR in Anova(car) and p-values

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

I am having difficulty understanding the p-values of a `Anova(glm)` in the `car` package in terms of Type II error. Are they testing if a particular feature has a high typeII error and thus when the p-value is significant, it means that the feature is a good predictor of the response? Furthermore, what is the difference between using the Wald vs the LR when doing this test?

Comment: Are you confusing *Type II Sum of Squares* with *Type II Error*?

Comment: A (reproducible) example would help.